# Python Make function without break or continue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function

```
def getInput(rows, cols, myList):
    myList = [[0]*(cols-2) for i in range(rows-2)] #creates the board
    for i in myList: # adds -1 to beginning and end of each list to make border
        i.append(-1)
        i.insert(0,-1)
    myList.insert(0,[-1]*(cols)) #adds top border
    myList.append([-1]*(cols)) #adds bottom border

    while True:
        rows = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on or 'q' to exit: ")
        if rows == 'q': # if q then end while loop
            break
        cols = input("Please enter the column of a cell to turn on: ")
        print()
        myList[int(rows)][int(cols)] = 1 # changes chosen cells from 0(dead) to 1(alive)
    return myList
```

And I need to know a way to make this function without a break or continue in it.

Comment: Show us your whole function, and either `return` inside your `while` loop or reconsider `while True:`

Comment: Could you explain **why** you don't want to have a `break` or `continue`? Knowing more about your actual constraints will allow people to provide better answers.

Comment: @Aroch1234 If your query was resolved, don't forget to [accept (and upvote) one of the answers below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
...
rows = ""
while rows != 'q':
    rows = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on or 'q' to exit: ")
    if rows != 'q': # if q then end while loop
        cols = input("Please enter the column of a cell to turn on: ")
        print()
        myList[int(rows)][int(cols)] = 1 # changes chosen cells from 0(dead) to 1(alive)
return myList
```

You go into the if block only when the rows is not True, and if in any run, rows is initialized to `"q"`, then the while loop will automatically terminate in the next run.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable which will hold the boolean `True` value and can be turn to `False` in your required base condition of `if rows == 'q':`.

```
status = True
while status:
    rows = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on or 'q' to exit: ")
    if rows == 'q':
        status = False
        continue
    cols = input("Please enter the column of a cell to turn on: ")
    print()
    myList[int(rows)][int(cols)] = 1
return myList
```

If you don't want to make use of both `break` and `continue` statement. Than you should return `myList`, as it will exit from your function terminating the while loop.

```
if rows == 'q':
    return myList
```

Comment: The second one works but I can't use continue either

Comment: And I would like to know the reason of  why you don't want to use `break` and `continue`.

Comment: its for a class and they take points off for using break and continue

Comment: Than you should return myList inside of the if conditon. `if rows == 'q': return myList`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the else to avoid needing a continue.

```
def getInput(rows, cols, myList):
    myList = [[0]*(cols-2) for i in range(rows-2)] #creates the board
    for i in myList: # adds -1 to beginning and end of each list to make border
        i.append(-1)
        i.insert(0,-1)
    myList.insert(0,[-1]*(cols)) #adds top border
    myList.append([-1]*(cols)) #adds bottom border
    run = True

    while run:
        rows = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on or 'q' to exit: ")
        if rows == 'q': # if q then end while loop
            run = False
        else:
            cols = input("Please enter the column of a cell to turn on: ")
            print()
            myList[int(rows)][int(cols)] = 1 # changes chosen cells from 0(dead) to 1(alive)
    return myList
```